# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that for all $x \in G$, $x^2 \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Letting $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that for every $x\in G$, $x^{2}\in H$. So, which of the following is true?

a. $H$ is a normal subgroup containing $G'$.

b. $H$ is a normal abelian subgroup.

c. $H=G$.

d. $H$ is a maximal subgroup.

**c** need not be true. For example, consider $H=2\Bbb Z$ and $G=\Bbb Z$. I want to know which of the **a**, **b** or **d** is true?

Thank you.

Comment: For $(d)$, do you mean the subgroup $\{0,4\}=H\leq\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$? If so, then it is not a counterexample since $1+1=2\notin H$. Or do you mean something else by your notation?

Comment: @ Clayton Thank you. The question is edited.

Comment: what does $G'$ denote?

Comment: The commutator subgroup of $G$

Comment: [Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ such that $x^2 \in H$ , $\forall x\in G$ . Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398422/let-h-be-a-subgroup-of-a-group-g-such-that-x2-in-h-forall-x-in-g)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hints:

(1) In any group $\,G\,$ , the subgroup $\,G^n:=\langle\,x^n\;;\;x\in G\,\,,\,n\in\Bbb N\,\rangle\,$ is normal (in fact, it is a fully invariang subgroup)

(2) Any group $\,G\,$ for which $\,x^2=1\,\,\,\forall\,x\in G\,$ is abelian

(3) In *your case*, $\,H\triangleleft G\,$ and $\,G/H\,$ is abelian.

(4) $\,\forall\,N\triangleleft G\,$ in any group $\,G\,$  , $\,G/N\,$ is abelian iff $\,G'\leq N\,$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Note that in $\mathbb Q_8$, the subgroup $H=\{1,-1\}$ is as you defined above but it is not maximal at all. Nice suggestions +1

Comment: @Babak I do not understand that how $H$ is normal

Comment: @aliakbar: Google the Quaternion subgroups to see that $H$ is a char subgroup so is normal.

Comment: @aliakbar, look: $$\forall\,x,g\in G\;,\;\;g^{-1}x^ng=\left(g^{-1}xg\right)^n $$ and this shows that *any* generator of $\,G^n\,$ remains a generator of $\,G^n\,$ after being conjugated (an element of $\,G\,$ to the $\,n-$th power) , so $\,G^n\,$ is normal as it is generated by a normal set. In the case of $\,\{-1,1\}\leq Q_8\,$ , you can try to prove the beautiful lemma: if a group has one unique element $\,t\,$ of order two, then $\,\{1,t\}\leq Z(G)\,$  which, in particular, means that this subgroup's normal.

Comment: @ DonAntonio I still do not understand why $H$ is a normal subgroup. I would be most grateful if you would explain

Comment: $$\forall\,g,x\in G\,\,,\,g^{-1}x^ng=(g^{-1}xg)^n\Longrightarrow$$ every conjugate of a generator of $\,G^n\,$ is again a generator of $\,G^n\,$ and thus $\,G^n\triangleleft G\,$ . For $\,n=2\,$ we get that $\,(xG)^2=x^2G=\overline 1\in G/G^2\Longrightarrow G/G^2\,$ is abelian, and since $\,G^2\leq H\,$ then $\,H/G^2\leq G/G^2\Longrightarrow H/G^2\triangleleft G/G^2\Longleftrightarrow H\triangleleft G\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you very much

Comment: @DonAntonio I have another question on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285076/which-of-the-following-statements-is-not-true  Please help me.

Comment: What does the notation with the triangle mean: $\,H\triangleleft G\,$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about $(a)$ and $(b)$, let me think about it for a while.

For $(d)$, $H$ need not be maximal, for we can consider a group of order $8$, where all elements have order $2$ except for the identity. Then $H=\{e,a\}$ is a subgroup, every element not in $H$ has order $2$, i.e., $g^2=e\in H$, but $J=\{e,a,b,ab\}$ is a subgroup which contains $H$, hence $H$ is not maximal.