# Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ such that $x^2 \in H$ , $\forall x\in G$ . Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ such that $x^2 \in H$, $\forall x\in G$. Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

---

I have tried to using the definition but failed. Can someone help me please.

Comment: I assume you mean $x^2\in H$ for all $x\in G$?

Comment: Assuming that, hint: Note that $H$ contains the subgroup generated by all the elements of the form $x^2$, which is normal. What do you know about the quotient of $G$ with that normal subgroup?

Comment: Which part did you not understand?

Comment: $H$ did not become normal. But the subgroup $\left< x^2\mid x\in G\right>$ is normal and contained in $H$.

Comment: This question has a counter part also, saying, then prove that G/H(the quotient group) is abelian. Can anyone prove this?

Answer (score 32):

$H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ $\iff\forall~h\in H ~\forall~ g\in G:g^{-1}hg \in H$

$g^{-1}hg=g^{-1}g^{-1}ghg=(g^{-1})^2h^{-1}hghg=(g^{-1})^2h^{-1}(hg)^2\in H(hg\in G \to (hg)^2\in H)$  then  $$g^{-1}hg \in H$$

Comment: This is very nice.+1

Comment: That's the elementary solution we were looking for :) Good job. I was halfway there when you completed it.

Comment: I though do not understand why the poster deleted his post the first time...perhaps he feared the quick-downvoters...

Comment: @DonAntonio why did you delete your answer? The only part wrong was the index of the subgroups generated by squares (and it was essentially what I was hinting in my comments).

Comment: It looks like you're saying that $g^{-1}hg\in H$ implies $g^{-1}hg\in H$. Can you clarify what you're doing, here?

Comment: I already posted a new, hopefully corrected, one in the same spirit, @TobiasKildetoft .

Comment: @CameronBuie, the poster begins with $\,g^{-1}hg\,$ *without assuming anything* (well, only that $\,g\in G\;,\;h\in H\,$) , and he reaches the conclusion that this product is in $\,H\,$

Comment: @Don: I see it now. Awkwardly presented, but a very nice approach.

Answer (score 3):

As I began to correct my former post: **Hints**

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;G^2:=\langle x^2\;;\;x\in G\rangle\lhd G\\
\bullet&\;\;\;G^2\le H\\
\bullet&\;\;\;\text{The group}\;\;G/G^2\;\;\text{is abelian and thus}\;\;G'\le G^2\end{align*}$$

Comment: I am not able to understand this hint. Can you please add more details. I mean what is the idea here.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician What part you don't understand? Is it clear what $\;G^2\;$ is and why it is a normal subgroup of $\;G\;$ ? Is it clear that this normal subgroup of $\;G\;$ is in fact *contained in* $\;H\;$ ? Maybe the last point...?

Comment: @DonAntonio , May i ask you something? I see now the derived set satisfies $G' \leq  G^2$. Then what's next step?? How can i show $H$ is normal of $G$?

Comment: Well, from what I wrote $\;G'\le H\;$, and any subgroup containing the derived subgroup is normal, so...